# How i can wrap any text from DB into a div class (jquery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-wrap

I have data from DB where is `<img>` tag and some text (different), so I need wrap thats text after img in to a div class.
How to do this?

Comment: share some code please, your question is not informative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your HTML is :

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="something.jpg" />
    Blabla bla blabla
</div>
```

Then you can do the following with JQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('.container');
    var $img = $container.find('img:first');

    var $imgTag = $img.detach(); // Temporary remove the <img /> tag
    $container.wrapInner('<div class="myWrapper" />'); // Wrap the text
    $container.prepend($imgTag); // Append the img tag that was removed
});
```

You can see the result here (by inspecting the element with a browser tool)

http://jsfiddle.net/G6xVG/2/

Comment: Its very good, but image has double copy after refresh the page.

Comment: Can't do more for you until i see your HTML and Javascript code.

Comment: My code like on example (<div class="container">
    <img src="something.jpg" />
    Blabla bla blabla
</div>) but all inside the "container" is import from BD with special tag, but code in browser the same as in example.